# Wacky window icon when using environment variable in Windows shortcut(.lnk)

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

I'd like to use environment variable in my .lnk file so that my .lnk file and their associated icons can be portable across different Windows machines. It almost works but there is an uncomfortable point: When I double click a lnk file to launch the shortcut(a CMD window), the CMD window does not recognize my assigned icon with env-var expansion in it path, for example:

```
%CHJDIR%\Chjcmds\zgreen.ico
```

See my screen shot below:

[image]

Any way to cope with this problem?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to set the icon on a `cmd.exe` window.

Comment: It sure can if I assign absolute dir ``c:\chj`` instead of ``%CHJDIR%`` .